# How to create a command that triggers executable file of your gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

For example, I have a gem called **mygem** and I want to start executable file with a command `mygem`.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the RubyGems guide for [how to add an executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable).

The primary steps are:

1. Add your script to the gem's `/bin` directory
2. Your script must be executable in the filesystem `chmod a+x bin/<yourfile>`
3. Make sure your script starts with a proper [shebang](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/shebang.html)
4. Add the script to the `.executables` section of your gemspec

Note you will still have to build and install your gem locally to run the command without a path as you are trying to do in the screenshot.

More info in [building executable gems](http://robdodson.me/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/).

Comment: Note that the `.executables` list in your gemspec only works for Ruby scripts.